# A light Wordpress take a minute to load

Tags: wordpress, performance

I work on a Wordpress website that doesn't include any big plugin. But as you can see, the load process is completely "broken".

I use Wordpress 5.2.2, i already tried to turn off plugins one by one. Nothing works.

[image: Performance screenshot]

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use wp-rocket plugin for fix those problem. i already use it for my clients website and its very helpful. Thanks